# PHP queue jobs in centOS

Tags: php, scheduling, centos

I wrote a PHP shell script which include queuing jobs in centOS with 'at' command.
The queue jobs may vary in time and contents which means the system need to keep quite a large number of jobs.
The application logic will also be a bit difficult to setup with cronjob.
Is there a limit in number of queue jobs in centOS or is there any alternative way of queuing jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing to a "distributed" queue such as [dropr](https://www.dropr.org/) or an implementation of  [AMPQ](http://www.amqp.org/).

Comment: How about any other ways? if there is no limit in queuing jobs, i would like to use it.

Comment: A message queue would essentially be unlimited, the only disadvantage is you would need to write a program to read from the queue and kick off the jobs. Alternatively you could use a database for the same purpose (IE, write jobs to DB and then have another process read from them). This would be easy to setup since you are using PHP, and again would support a large number of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of job processes may slow down the whole server. It could happen if there are many of them which started at the same time (or simply work at the same time). If you have 20 hard working processes and only 4 CPU cores they will struggle for CPU and it should switch between them very often.

I'd suggest using a message queue and a pool of workers. You can start from a filesystem queue (or mysql based). You have to install a php lib only, no any extra services. Later if needed, you can switch to real message queue brokers with less effort.

I would recommend using [enqueue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev) library.